# How to join tables by Wild card Like/ Instr

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have problem using JOIN on a table to another table base on Wildcard "*".

Basically, I have a table "A" with wildcard in some records already in the primary key like so.

173221-02-********** , field 2 , ...

173221-01-99999 , field 2 , ...

173221-03-99999 , field 2 , ...

etc.

On Table "B", i have records like this

173221-02-11111 , $20

173221-02-22222 , $50

173221-01-99999 , $30.

I want to sum up table B based on the code on table A like this below:

173221-02-********* , $70

173221-01-99999, $30

173221-03-99999 , $0

In excel i can achieve this by using

```
=sumif(table A Code, Table B code, Table B Dollars)
```

But in Access 2007 SQL below I am stuck. 
This is what i have worked on so far,

```
SELECT a.Code , SUM(b.Dollar)
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON
a.code LIKE b.code
GROUP BY a.code
```

but this only returns

173221-02-********** ,

173221-01-99999 ,  $30

173221-03-99999 ,

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

ANSWER:

with help from comments below, switching to

```
b.code LIKE a.code
```

fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your join condition be the other way around? i.e. if A has the wildcards, shouldn't it be B.code like A.code?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the data, you might be able to join on the first x characters.

Comment: yep that was it, thansk Jaaz Cole